# Modules and typeclasses in Ur/Web

Tags: module, sml, ml

I'm playing around with modules in [Ur/Web](http://www.impredicative.com/ur/) and can not figure out how to infer standard (show, read, eq) typeclass instances along with module system. Consider the following code:

```
signature USER = sig
    type id
    type password
    val id_read : read id
    val pass_read : read password
    val id_show : show id
    val login : { Id : id, Password : password } -> transaction bool
    val whoami : transaction (option id)
end

functor MakeUser(M : sig type id
                         type password
                    end) : USER = struct
    type id = M.id
    type password = M.password

    table user : { Id : id, Password : password }
                     PRIMARY KEY Id
    cookie c : { Id : id, Password : password }
    fun login r =
        b <- oneRowE1 (SELECT COUNT( * ) > 0
                       FROM user
                       WHERE user.Id = {[r.Id]}
                         AND user.Password = {[r.Password]});
        if b then
            setCookie c { Value = r, Expires = None, Secure = False };
            return True
        else return False
    val whoami =
        cc <- getCookie c;
        case cc of
            None => return None
          | Some r =>
            b <- oneRowE1 (SELECT COUNT( * ) > 0
                           FROM user
                           WHERE user.Id = {[r.Id]}
                             AND user.Password = {[r.Password]});
            if b then
                return (Some r.Id)
            else
                return None
end

structure User = MakeUser(struct
                              type id = string
                              type password = string
                          end)


fun main () =
    me <- User.whoami;
    return <xml><body>
      <h1>Logged in as : {cdata (show me)}</h1>
    </body></xml>
and login () =
    return <xml><body>
      <form>
        <textbox{#Id}/>
        <textbox{#Password}/>
        <submit action={signin}/>
      </form>
    </body></xml>
and signin r =
    success <- User.login { Id = readError r.Id, Password = readError r.Password };
    if success then main()
    else login ()
```

this code does not compile with the errors

```
Unmatched signature item Item:  val id_read : read id
Unmatched signature item Item:  val password_read : read password
Unmatched signature item Item:  val id_show : show id
```

Must I implement those instances in functor's argument explicitly or it is still possible to infer them? How to make this code to work? And in general, I have not found a "good" documentation about typeclasses in Ur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Adam](https://github.com/achlipala), who pointed me to the solution:

> It's necessary to include lines like `val id_read = _` in the functor
>   body.

Also had to add

```
val inj_id : sql_injectable id
val inj_prim_id : sql_injectable_prim id
val inj_pass : sql_injectable password
```

to the functor's argument signature.

So, I ended up with the following definition for `MakeUser` functor:

```
functor MakeUser(M : sig type id
                         type password
                         val id_read : read id
                         val pass_read : read password
                         val id_show : show id
                         val inj_id : sql_injectable id
                         val inj_prim_id : sql_injectable_prim id
                         val inj_pass : sql_injectable password
                    end) : USER = struct
    type id = M.id
    type password = M.password
    val id_read = _
    val pass_read = _
    val id_show = _

    table user : { Id : id, Password : password }
                     PRIMARY KEY Id
    cookie c : { Id : id, Password : password }
    fun login r =
        b <- oneRowE1 (SELECT COUNT( * ) > 0
                       FROM user
                       WHERE user.Id = {[r.Id]}
                         AND user.Password = {[r.Password]});
        if b then
            setCookie c { Value = r, Expires = None, Secure = False };
            return True
        else return False
    val whoami =
        cc <- getCookie c;
        case cc of
            None => return None
          | Some r =>
            b <- oneRowE1 (SELECT COUNT( * ) > 0
                           FROM user
                           WHERE user.Id = {[r.Id]}
                             AND user.Password = {[r.Password]});
            if b then
                return (Some r.Id)
            else
                return None
end
```